# getting the id of something that has been dropped

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a drag & drop videoplayer and I'm stuck.

I have several div dropzones and I want the videos (div id/picture of a video that will be linked to a videofile) that have been dropped, to play one after another. Im gonna do that with an array. My problem is I can't get the dropzones to tell me what has been dropped into them. I've tried several things but nothing worked.

I'm using:

```
<div id="divDropzone1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="Video1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><img   src="images/Video1.jpg" onclick="Video1()"></div>

function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass an identifier to the drop function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
```

That line of code is the key, if you change `drop()` to the following

```
function drop(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
console.log(data);
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

You will see that you can get the id of the element that you dropped.

Comment: I've already tried alert(); but nothing happened. Same with console.log nothing shows in the console. Its probably because the code runs before any of the draggin etc. is done. I've made a button for debugging but even if I make a global variable: _temp = data; I get uncought referanceError.  



Omg i was working in a backup of my js file no wonder nothing worked ok I got it now thanks.

Comment: I've been able to make it work now. But I have another related question. With data I get the id of the div but there are several elements in the div. I've used the divs id which is the name of the video file and just added + ".ogg". Now I need to access the other elements that are contained in the div. My workaround only works if I access one element.

Comment: you could use jQuery simply enough to grab other attributes from the element that has the id